# How do configure my `travis.yaml` `jobs.include` and `before_install` to install stack for macOS?

Tags: macos, travis-ci, haskell-stack

Though I've implemented the steps [described in the instructions](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/travis_ci/?highlight=travis#installing-stack)

```
before_install:
# Download and unpack the stack executable
- mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
- export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
- travis_retry curl -L https://get.haskellstack.org/stable/linux-x86_64.tar.gz | tar xz --wildcards --strip-components=1 -C ~/.local/bin '*/stack'
```

in [my `travis.yaml`](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/21bbb39860fb1a66d7c340331724ee0abf1c5481/.travis.yml) these [fail](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/jobs/441071972) when I attempt to build on macOS using

```
jobs:
  include:
  ...
  - name: "LTS 9.6 (Haskell for macOS)"
    os: osx
    osx_image: xcode10
    env: ...
    ...
```

with

```
tar: Option --wildcards is not supported
Usage:
  List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    tar --help
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 597)
The command "curl -L https://www.stackage.org/stack/linux-x86_64" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 597)
The command "curl -L https://www.stackage.org/stack/linux-x86_64" failed. Retrying, 3 of 3.
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 597)
The command "curl -L https://www.stackage.org/stack/linux-x86_64" failed 3 times.
```

How do I modify my `travis.yaml` `jobs.include` and `before_install` to install stack for macOS?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

1. I wouldn't use `travis_retry` here, since `curl` has the [`--retry` flag](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--retry) that works better.
2. macOS uses BSD `tar`, not GNU `tar`. You can either:

   1. Find a common flag that works on both
   2. Install [`gnu-tar`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnu-tar), and use that instead. (This formula requires more than just `brew install gnu-tar`, if you want to execute it as `tar`, so be sure to set it up correctly.)

Comment: Can you explain what the parenthetical remark means? How do I invoke gnu-tar once installed?

Comment: This is what I see when I run `brew install gnu-tar`: https://gist.github.com/BanzaiMan/e627ec19b86dc01eefa85eb787685755

Comment: That doesn't work. First of all I need to use `travis_retry`. But more importantly gnu-tar doesn't seem to have worked as expected on macOS, because when I try to execute `stack` [I get](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/jobs/441109849) " /Users/travis/.local/bin/stack: cannot execute binary file", which suggests that something has gone wrong with the extraction of `stack`?

Comment: You are downloading `https://www.stackage.org/stack/linux-x86_64`, which sounds like a Linux executable. I would be pretty surprised if the Mac could execute it.

Comment: As for `travis_retry`: You notice that on https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/jobs/441071972#L93 the command that actually failed was `tar`; and because of it, `curl` failed due to the broken pipe. You now have a misleading message on https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/jobs/441071972#L102. Not sure if the retries are actually running the piped command `curl | tar`, either, since there's no error message on `tar`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's from `curl` using the flag you suggested (which requires an argument it seems unnecessary to sort out if I can just use `travis_retry`, unless you can explain 1 a bit). 2 isn't really the solution either, since `brew install stack` does the trick on macOS.

Comment: I explained why `travis_retry` is not the best thing to do here in the previous comment. My `gnu-tar` comment was based on your previous incomplete implementation where you assumed that the file you are downloading would work on the Mac. If whatever the solution you found instead of mine does the trick, I'm happy for you.