# How do I configure my Travis CI builds for Haskell for ARM64 architectures?

Tags: haskell, arm, travis-ci, haskell-stack

Currently I have the [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/f8e161192cf0153f851a0ff62dbf76e5907e2dd2/.travis.yml) below and would like to move from the default `arch` to `arm64` or even `arm64-graviton2` (and various `dist`s) but can't figure out how to install the right Haskell Stack distribution for ARM64 (or if it even exists).

How do I configure my Travis CI builds for Haskell as ARM64 architectures?

```
os: linux


# Choose a lightweight base image; we provide our own build tools.
language: generic

# Caching so the next build will be fast too.
cache:
  directories:
  - "$HOME/.stack"

# GHC depends on GMP. You can add other dependencies here as well.
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - libgmp-dev

# ...

before_install:
# Download and unpack the stack executable -- https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/travis_ci/?highlight=travis
- mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
- export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
# Aquire the stack aprioriate to the os used -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52796679/656912
- if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then  brew update ; brew install stack ; fi
- if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" != "osx" ]]; then  travis_retry curl -L https://get.haskellstack.org/stable/linux-x86_64.tar.gz | tar xz --wildcards --strip-components=1 -C ~/.local/bin '*/stack' ;  fi
- stack --version
```

Comment: Have you tried using a Docker container? I've had success with containers to do a variety of things on arm64-graviton2 with TravisCI. Is there a specific error message you're getting?